# CSS: adding a box around a form breaks the formatting

Tags: css, border-box

I added a box around the form underneath the main image. Now the controls are distributed on 3 instead of 2 rows. I tried everything but i can't get it back so that all controlls are only aligned on 2 rows...

Has to do with the border-box, content-box I guess, but I am not able to get it right...

Form ist NOT ok: https://www.auto-pfandhaus.ch/autopfand-kredit-lp/
Form is OK: https://www.auto-pfandhaus.ch/3-schritte-zum-geld/

Can somebody help? I would appreciate it a lot?

Thanks.
Cesare

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here to troubleshoot?

Comment: change the width of `.radio` and `.exfield` on that page to `212px`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using definite widths, set widths to 212px for your .exfield and .radio classes.

If you want to use percentages, 19.5% should work